# Converting from .xlsx to .txt

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that converts each sheet of a spreadsheet into a .txt file. It works well, however, given the big number of exports (about 90 .txt files), I'd like to seek advice on how to speed it up.

```
Sub xlsxTotxt()

Dim i As Integer
Dim directory As String
Dim fname As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xTextFile As String
Dim rdate As String

directory = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D576").Value
rdate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("E47").Value
i = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D577").Offset(i).Value <> ""
fname = Sheets("Macro").Range("D577").Offset(i).Value
Workbooks.Open (directory & fname)
For Each xWs In Workbooks(fname).Worksheets
xWs.Copy
xTextFile = directory & rdate & " - " & xWs.name & ".txt"
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=xTextFile, FileFormat:=xlText
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next
Workbooks(fname).Close
i = i + 1
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: VBA is single threaded. So you can only do one job at a time. Most of your time in this task is spent writing your 90 txt files. You could speed this up by calling an export function on each file from a batch file or PowerShell script. Getting say 4 excel sessions to run at once. Or you could use your vba to loop through the list, and then Shell out to multiple excel's. Each loading your extract code, and then running on the provided workbook. You'd be looking at the Shell command, and then Excel command line parameters, and using workbook event, and order of sheets in command line.

Answer (score 11):

---

### Your code is incredibly fragile

```
directory = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D576").Value
rdate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("E47").Value
```

If a **single** row/column gets added or deleted or moved, those ranges are going to move and your code is going to fail completely.

If you can, those values should be in a dedicated sheet, not buried below 500 lines of other stuff. If not, **name your ranges**.

[image]

So, let's say you take cell `D576` and name it `Directory_Path` or something similar. Now, rather than

```
directory = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D576").Value
```

which is incredibly fragile, you can use

```
directory = ThisWorkbook.Range("Directory_Path").Value
```

and so long as nobody actually deletes said row/column, that will always point to the right place.

---

### Use `With`

Rather than re-referencing the same object over and over, you can use a `With` statement to hold a reference. Like so:

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xTextFile, FileFormat:=xlText
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Becomes

```
With Application.ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs Filename:=xTextFile, FileFormat:=xlText
    .Saved = True
    .Close
End With
```

**much** clearer and easier to read.

---

### Handle things in the right order

Specifically your `Application.[Settings]`. Anything *meta* like that should go right at the start and right at the end of the method(s) it applies to. This allows you to confirm, at a glance, what the internal state of your method is and check that things are set/reset correctly. You should also disable `Application.EnableEvents` and `Application.Calculation` for significant extra speed. Like so:

```
Sub xlsxTotxt()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With


    ...


    Code


    ...


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

---

### Use descriptive naming

Code should be written for other people (including future you) to read. Names should be **descriptive, unambiguous and concise**. In that order. I highly recommend the [excellent, classic article on naming by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). But in short, things should sound like what they are.

`xTextFile`. What on earth is that? Looking at it I have no idea. If I had to guess, I'd say it's some kind of `file` object. Oh, it's the `filename` you want to `save` your text file under? Why not call it `newFilename`? Since it's a full filename (including directory path). Maybe `newFullfilename` or just `fullFilename` might be even more descriptive.

`xWs` suffers from the same problem. I can guess it's a `worksheet` object but beyond that? no idea. Since you just use it to iterate over the sheets in your workbook, maybe just call it `currentSheet`?

`fname`. Same thing. `filename`. Since it's the filename for the workbook you're opening, how about `targetWorkbookFilename`? Sure, it's long, but screen real estate is cheap, cognitive processing is not and that name's an awful lot easier to understand and work with.

Also, move your declarations near to where they're used. This helps you *see* the different parts of your method and helps you keep track of where you are, refer back to your declarations and see ways to split things up into logical sub-methods. Personally, I prefer to keep declarations outside of Loop structures, but that's personal preference.

---

### Objects are your friend

VBA has a huge, extensive, comprehensive object model for every Office Application. Use it.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro")
```

You refer to that sheet multiple times. Rather than continually repeating that reference, put it in a `worksheet` object and then just refer to the object.

```
Dim macroSheet As Worksheet
Set macroSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro")

Dim dateString As String
dateString = macroSheet.Range("E47").Value
```

Same with `Workbooks`.

```
Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D577").Offset(i).Value <> ""
fname = Sheets("Macro").Range("D577").Offset(i).Value
Workbooks.Open (directory & fname)
For Each xWs In Workbooks(fname).Worksheets
xWs.Copy
xTextFile = directory & rdate & " - " & xWs.name & ".txt"
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=xTextFile, FileFormat:=xlText
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Relying on `ActiveWorkbook` being the one you want is very fragile. Just make it a proper object and then your references will always be accurate:

```
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Set targetWorkbook  = Workbooks.Open (directory & fname)

...

For Each currentSheet In targetWorkbook.Sheets()

    ...

    With targetWorkbook
        .SaveAs filename:=xTextFile, FileFormat:=xlText
        .Saved = True
        .Close
    End With
```

---

### Indenting

Indenting is a wonderful way to let you *see* the structure of your Sub. It'll let you pick out nested-logic (`Loop`s, `If`s, `For`s, `With`s etc.) and very quickly get a rough idea for where the important stuff in your sub is. Compare:

```
Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D577").Offset(i).Value <> ""
fname = Sheets("Macro").Range("D577").Offset(i).Value
Workbooks.Open (directory & fname)
For Each xWs In Workbooks(fname).Worksheets
xWs.Copy
xTextFile = directory & rdate & " - " & xWs.name & ".txt"
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=xTextFile, FileFormat:=xlText
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next
Workbooks(fname).Close
i = i + 1
Loop
```

With

```
Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D577").Offset(i).Value <> ""

    fname = Sheets("Macro").Range("D577").Offset(i).Value
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fname)

    For Each xWs In Workbooks(fname).Worksheets

        xWs.Copy
        xTextFile = directory & rdate & " - " & xWs.Name & ".txt"

        With Application.ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs Filename:=xTextFile, FileFormat:=xlText
            .Saved = True
            .Close
        End With

    Next

    Workbooks(fname).Close
    i = i + 1

Loop
```

And suddenly you can **see** your program flow, and where the real work is happening, and where loops start/end, in just a glance. Adding some whitespace also goes a long way to helping readability.

---

### Putting it all together

```
Sub xlsxTotxt()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Dim parentDirectoryCell As Range
    Set parentDirectoryCell = ThisWorkbook.Range("Directory_Path")

    Dim parentDirectoryPath As String
    parentDirectoryPath = parentDirectoryCell.Value

    Dim dateString As String
    dateString = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("E47").Value


    Dim fullFilename As String
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbookFilename As String

    Dim rowOffset As Long
    rowOffset = 1

    targetWorkbookFilename = parentDirectoryCell.Offset(rowOffset).Value
    Do While targetWorkbookFilename <> ""

        Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(parentDirectoryPath & targetWorkbookFilename)

        For Each currentSheet In targetWorkbook.Sheets()

            currentSheet.Copy
            fullFilename = parentDirectoryPath & dateString & " - " & currentSheet.Name & ".txt"

            With targetWorkbook
                .SaveAs Filename:=fullFilename, FileFormat:=xlText
                .Saved = True
                .Close
            End With

        Next currentSheet

        targetWorkbook.Close

        rowOffset = rowOffset + 1
        targetWorkbookFilename = parentDirectoryCell.Offset(rowOffset).Value

    Loop

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: A thorough and indepth analysis of the quality of his code. But you don't answer his question

Comment: The bits about `Application.[Settings]` should make a noticeable difference. And CR is not automatically about giving OPs what they want. It's about reviewing \*any and all\* parts of the code for improvements.

Comment: Or to put it another way, I think all the other points will be of greater benefit to the OPs code than focusing on speed. They're opening/creating/saving/closing many many workbooks. There is only so much you can do to speed that up.

Comment: Hi Zak, 
thanks for your reply I find your suggestion very interesting and helpful.
I work in Finance and I do know only the basic of VBA and coding more in general, on top of this the above code is part of a much longer procedure that I've recently took on from another Team... I had the feeling that some part of the code could be improved and you just confirmed that!
Again thanks for your help and the very detail explanation.

Comment: @Zak, another question...I'm trying your code but it stops at     `targetWorkbook.Close`    and I have the following error "Run-time error '-2147221080 (800401a8)': Automation error   
Any suggestion on how what is causing this?

Comment: @NicolaTorrisi Do you know how to debug VBA (in general)? If you do, just step through and make sure, at every point, that all variables are what they're supposed to be and all methods are doing what they're supposed to be doing. If not, [come to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41555/vba-debugging-help) and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: @NicolaTorrisi Just re-reading, it's because the workbook has already been closed in the `with` loop. So the code is trying to close a workbook that no longer exists. Hence the error.

Answer (score 3):

Nicola, 
To answer your original question.. How to make it go faster. Since you say you are having to take this over, and there is a wider program involved, here's an interesting solution to add to your environment.

**Setup**

You will need 2 workbooks.

Workbook1 : Manager.xls

Workbook2 : Runner.xls

Manager.xls has the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub manage()

    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In Range("booksToExtract")
         shellout item
    Next item

End Sub

Public Sub shellout(ByVal val As String)

    ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
    Shell """c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE"" /r " & val & " runner.xls /r "

End Sub
```

Runner.xls will do you work of extracting the code; there is a bit of management code to identify when a book to extract is available.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function waitForNewWorkBook() As String

    While Workbooks.Count = 1
        DoEvents
    Wend

    If Workbooks(1).Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        waitForNewWorkBook = Workbooks(2).Name
        Exit Function
    End If

    waitForNewWorkBook = Workbooks(1).Name

End Function
Public Sub auto_open()

    Dim workbookName As String

    workbookName = waitForNewWorkBook
    ExtractCode workbookName

    'Cleanup
    Workbooks(workbookName).Close
    Application.Quit

End Sub

Public Sub ExtractCode(ByVal workbookName As String)

    Dim oWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim oBook As Workbook

    Set oBook = Workbooks(workbookName)

    ' get your filename format here.
    ' loop through your worksheets and extract here.

    oBook.SaveAs oBook.Name & ".txt", xlText

    Call oBook.Close(False)

End Sub
```

*Assumptions*

I've assumed all the workbooks are in the same folder, and the extract folder is also in the same folder. You can modify if needed.

**How does this work**

- Part One

The Manager workbook loops through all your available workbooks, and calls the shellout method.

The shellout method, calls the VBA Shell method, which runs the string provided and opens a new excel session in a new process, and in that excel opens the runner.xls book, and the next book in your list, both as readonly.

The shellout method will not wait for the excel session to die before returning to the manager, so the manager will just "spawn" as many excel sessions as there are books in the list. You can modify this behaviour to check the number of concurrently running excel session in the processors if you want.

In my example I have I created 10 workbooks, and ran them, at this point I should see in the process explorer, 10 excel sessions, each trying to get processor time. Sadly I only have 2 cores, so the manager sheet is taking one process, and I can only run one other process. But if you have 4 or 16 processors, you could extract 3 or 15 excels at a time.

- Part Two

Now that each of the excel extracts 'runner.xls myExtractBookX.xls' is opened the runner.xls will have started the `auto_open` method.

waitForNewWorkbook does as it says. Wait untill the myExtractBookX.xls is open and returns the name of the file.

then we run `ExtractCode` which is the code to extract your workbook. I leave it to you to implement how you want to extract a workbook.

Now you have a multithreaded excel application. but don't tell anyone that, because excel is actually single threaded, and actually we've just spawned multiple excel processes to run on any free cores.

**Finale**

If you run this from a command line it can really get interesting...

```
for /f "usebackq" %i in (`dir /s/b pnl*.xls`) do "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" /r %i /r runner.xls
```

Comment: auto_open is a special excel method. Excel will look for this method as well as the workbook_open method and run them if it finds them. To stop them running when you open the workbooks, hold down the shift key when opening the workbook.

Answer (score 3):

I found that 2 additional Application properties make a noticeable difference: `.Calculation` and `.EnableEvents`. Runtime came down from 20s to 6.5s with 2 files, from 30s to 13s with 3 files:

```
Sub xlsxTotxt()
    Dim fileno As Integer
    Dim directory As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xTextFile As String
    Dim rdate As String
    Dim namelist As Range
    Dim runtime As Variant

    ' runtime = Timer  # decomment if runtime is to be measured
    ToggleWaitMode  ' switch Application properties

    rdate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("E47").Value
    directory = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D576").Value
    Set namelist = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D577")

    fileno = 0
    Do While namelist.Offset(fileno).Value <> ""
        fname = namelist.Offset(fileno).Value
        Workbooks.Open (directory & fname)
        For Each xWs In Workbooks(fname).Worksheets
            xTextFile = directory & rdate & " - " & xWs.name & ".txt"
            xWs.Copy   ' create a new workbook from this sheet
            With ActiveWorkbook
                .SaveAs filename:=xTextFile, FileFormat:=xlText
                .Saved = True
                .Close
            End With
        Next xWs
        Workbooks(fname).Close
        fileno = fileno + 1
    Loop

    ToggleWaitMode False
    ' runtime = Timer - runtime
    ' MsgBox runtime
End Sub

Public Sub ToggleWaitMode(Optional ByVal wait As Boolean = True)
    With Excel.Application
        .Calculation = IIf(wait, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
        .Cursor = IIf(wait, xlWait, xlDefault)
        .StatusBar = IIf(wait, "Please wait...", False)

        .DisplayAlerts = Not wait
        .ScreenUpdating = Not wait
        .EnableEvents = Not wait
    End With
End Sub
```

Switching properties of the Application object is so common in macros that I use a public function of it's own for this, `ToggleWaitMode()` (found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60323/inefficient-slow-loop-with-calculations-in-worksheet/60331)). In addition to the original settings it suppresses auto-macros and switches off the recalculation.
Finally I've used some of the good advice about use of objects instead of direct references etc. found in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of time in your program will be spent *opening* the workbooks. It's a terribly slow operation. If you can avoid that, you'll see massive performance gains.

> That's great, but how do you expect me to export these *without opening them*?

By using ADODB to connect to the *closed* file and *query* the sheets. Then you can write the results of those queries to text file.

Comment: I haven't downvoted a CR answer in a long time, but IMO this either needs to be more detailed, or it needs to be a comment.

Comment: @Zak it's definitely not a comment. I feel it's a legitimate review of the performance of the code and a way to make that better. What kind of detail are you looking for here?

Comment: IMO, "use X", by itself, isn't a particularly helpful CR answer.

Comment: I'm happy to edit @Zak, but I need a bit more to go on here.

Comment: Put it this way, the OP is evidently quite new to VBA. I know the first time somebody said "you should use ADODB" to me, I had no idea what that was, took one look at some google searches and decided it was *way* above my ability. Here, I would just add a couple of sentences saying what ADODB is, what you use it for, and maybe a MCVE of extracting data from a file using it. When you're being introduced to an alien topic, that makes all the difference in the world.